# Difference between 'elude', 'escape', and 'evade' with "understanding"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Difference between 'elude', 'escape', and 'evade' in this context.

The three terms have rather similar meanings, but I found [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-elude-evade-and-escape) that explains the difference.

> elude : escape from or avoid (a danger, enemy, or pursuer), typically in a skilful or cunning way, eg "He tried to elude the
> security men by sneaking through a back door"
>
> evade : avoid dealing with or accepting (something unpleasant or
> morally or legally required) eg “He continually evades paying taxes.”
>
> escape : breaking free from confinement or control. eg “The prisoners
> of war escaped from the camp.”
>
> ELUDE = avoid a physical enemy and not get caught
>
> EVADE = avoid a moral obligation
>
> ESCAPE = after being caught by an enemy and confined, you break free

In view of this, I'd like to know if this difference can be applied when these words are used to refer specifically to a lack of understanding.

Example:

> The reason for his actions evades/eludes/escapes our understanding.

An [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=escapes%20our%20understanding%2Cevades%20our%20understanding%2Celudes%20%20our%20understanding%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cescapes%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevades%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celudes%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cescapes%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevades%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celudes%20our%20understanding%3B%2Cc0) search shows how evades in this case is less used. But do they have the same meaning?

Comment: Are you asking for a full explanation of the the precise difference among those three words when used **literally**, or which of them is better when used **figuratively** with "*our understanding*"?

Comment: @gotube. Only when used about 'our understanding' (I edited  my post for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quora quote you give refers to the literal meanings of those words, but in your context, you're only interested in a figurative, metaphorical meaning. Metaphorical meanings are necessarily less precise.

As your Ngram search shows, "elude" and "escape" correlate much better with "understanding" than "evade". The reason is that "evade" includes the nuance of being *intentional*. Something can "elude" or "escape" without having that purpose, but to "evade" is to purposefully avoid something.

Since it doesn't make sense in this metaphor that a reason would be purposefully trying to get away from our understanding, only "elude" and "escape" work.

They're both good. "Escape" is a basic word, while "elude" feels more elevated and mysterious.